# ng-template to Variable from src

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to load the contents of my template into a variable. At the moment my Code looks like this.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="a.html" src="templates/a.html"></script>
```

**JS**

```
vm.template = $templateCache.get('a.html');
console.log("Template: " + vm.template);
```

This should Load the contents of 'templates/a.html' into vm.template. Sadly this does not work. The variable vm.template doesn't contain the template.

[image: The variable does not contain the template]

What I found out while testing is that if i write the contents of the template directly into the script tags like this

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="a.html">Hello!</script>
```

It actually works.

[image: The variable contains the template]

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: @Rohit Yes. Its says so in the title that i want to load the contents into the variable from the source, not from inside the script tags..

Comment: You should check this [http://plnkr.co/edit/E00OhHeccMZ3jcqmy9qh?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/E00OhHeccMZ3jcqmy9qh?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using src on ng-template may not work:

You can either use an ng-include:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="a.html">
    <div ng-include="'templates/a.html'"></div>
</script>
```

or do this in your routing config:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: 'templates/a.html',
            controller: 'aController'
        }).when("/second", {
            templateUrl: 'templates/b.html',
            controller: 'bController'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
});
```

Also, these does a `/templates/a.html` GET request to your server (make sure you have configured your statics)

Answer (score 0):

you can use directive:

```
.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: false,
      controller: function($attrs, $templateCache, $http, $log) {
        if($attrs['type'] != "text/ng-template" || !$attrs['src']){
          return;
        }

        var id = $attrs['id'] || $attrs['src'];
        var src = $attrs['src'];
        $log.debug('Loading %s template from %s', id, src);

        $http.get(src).then(function(response){
          $log.debug('Loaded template %s', id);
          $templateCache.put(id, response.data);
        });
      }
    };
  })
```